# ¿Cómo obtener una propiedad de un objeto pasado por parámetro?

Tags: c#

Tengo un método `TextFilter(object e)` que me pide como parámetro un objeto de cualquier tipo. Los objetos que le estoy pasando ambos `DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs` y `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` tienen casi las mismas propiedades. Las que me interesan son `ColumnIndex` y `RowIndex`.

Aqui esta el código...

```
private bool TextFilter(object e)        
{            
    DataTable dt = this.connection_Manager.DefaultProyectos;
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);        
    try
    {
        //Error elemento no contenido en e
        string value = dgvCBD[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), column = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;  
        dv.RowFilter =  $"[{column}] = '{value}'";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return (dv.Count == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Porqué no simplemente cambias tu método y recibes los parámetros `columnaIndex` y `RowIndex` en vez de un objeto?

Comment: Si no se puede enviar un string como parámetro. con el valor de la celda.

Comment: ¿?, podrías explicarte o [edit] tu pregunta y ver como lo quieres invocar. Leyendo tu comentario en una de las respuestas, quieres jugar con [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic).

Comment: Yo quería algo parecido a la respuesta que dio @Rasco pero con menos código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumo que lo que quieres hacer es trabajar con "duck typing": en vez de tener en cuenta el tipo del objeto, simplemente miras si tiene una propiedad o método que te interesa y lo usas.

C# permite eso mediante Reflection. Por ejemplo, para incrementar en 1 una propiedad de tipo entero llamada "columnaIndex":

```
 //using System.Reflection;

 var propiedad = objeto.GetType().GetProperty("columnaIndex");
 int valorAntiguo = (int)propiedad.GetValue(objeto);
 int valorNuevo = valorAntiguo + 1;
 propiedad.SetValue(objeto, valorNuevo);
```

Lecturas sugeridas:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Para el ejemplo que consideraste estás seteando un valor y no obteniendo. =)

Comment: @Davlio Añadí un ejemplo de cómo obtener un valor.

Comment: Me funcionó utilizando un cast `int ci = (int) propiedad.GetValue(e, null);` para los índices.

Comment: @JesseR.Jose Si la respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar a castear el objeto a cada uno de los tipos y, si tiene éxito, coger el valor de las propiedades:

```
int columnIndex;
int rowIndex;
if (e is DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs cellParsingEvent)
{
    columnIndex = cellParsingEvent.ColumnIndex;
    rowIndex = cellParsingEvent.RowIndex;
}
if (e is DataGridViewCellEventArgs cellEvent)
{
    columnIndex = cellEvent.ColumnIndex;
    rowIndex = cellEvent.RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: Parece mucho código yo creí que c# tenia una forma de detectar funciones also así como  `e["ColumnIndex"]` o algo parecido.

Comment: Sí, utilizando Reflection como te sugieren en otra respuesta pero, aunque en las últimas versiones del framework ha mejorado mucho el rendimiento al usar Reflection, yo no lo usaría para un caso tan simple